# How can I use a laptop as a gamepad?

Tags: networking, bluetooth, gaming, game-controller

I'd like to be able to use a laptop (or desktop) as a gamepad connected to another laptop. Is there any way this is possible? Google searches haven't come up with anything. In my situation, either a PC running Windows, a PC running a Linux distro, or a Mac running OSX could serve as the controller, so a solution for any platform will work.

I am hoping to find that software exists to do this automatically, but if the solution involves creating/running a script or using terminal commands, I am happy to do that. If I need to buy a special adapter (e.g. to connect two computers via USB) I am happy to do that as well.

Comment: i suppose using VNC and a different keyset for each player does not solve the issue?

Comment: It does not. The goal is to use a laptop as a second controller in a two-player game like Monaco. VNC would take over the first player's control. I'm guessing nobody has done this yet but I'm hoping someone will eventually answer with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It has different solution for  different game.
If you just want to use your laptop's keyboard,why do not try remote control ,like RDP,VNC...

Comment: I used [Win2Vnc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win2vnc/) for a long time to control the computer hooked up to my TV from my laptop, worked really well. You get the remote control of VNC but you don't use the bandwith on forwarding the video back.

Comment: You misunderstand. I want to plug in/connect the laptop and have it be recognized universally as a game controller to the extent an XBox controller is recognized.

Comment: Sorry about that,It Sounds difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/):

> Synergy lets you easily share your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers on your desk.